# Obtaining incomplete output

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

I want to obtain output from the 50 us states whereas I only obtain it for one. Here is my code:

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd

api_key=open(XXXX).read()
df=quandl.get('FMAC/HPI_AK',authtoken=api_key)

fiddy_states=pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
# we will print only the abbrev of the states
  for abbv in fiddy_states [0][0][1:] :
# print("FMAC/HPI_"+str(abbv))

query= "FMAC/HPI_"+str(abbv)
df=quandl.get(query,authtoken=api_key)
df.columns = [str(abbv)]

main_df=pd.DataFrame()

if main_df.empty:
    main_df= df
else:
    main_df=main_df.join(df)

print(main_df.head())
```

My actual output is :

```
                   WY
Date
1975-01-31  31.545673
1975-02-28  32.035235
1975-03-31  32.551748
1975-04-30  33.083411
1975-05-31  33.596747
```

Whereas I would like to obtain this data from the 50 states. The previous print (just after for in and commented ) shows i am referencing the 50 states

Comment: Can you show us what you would like to get and what you actually get?

Comment: Is there an indention error in your example? Seems like you need the .join block in the for loop. If it is, you are re-declaring main_df as an empty df in each iteration, which should be your problem.

Comment: Absolutely right Yeile, those 2 where the problems in the code.